# AIX :- Segmentation fault while calling shared library function in Clang based front end

Tags: aix, clang++

I am compiling a product code on `AIX using XL C/C++ Clang based front-end(V 16.1.0).`
I am trying to call a shared library function from a `.cpp` file. When the program is run, I receive a `segmentation fault(Illegal operand)`.

The core shows the program crashed while calling shared library function.

I am exporting all symbols from the shared library using -bexpfull. I also used `-brtl` and `-qrtti` for run time linking.

The code runs fine on `Xl C/C++ V11.1`.

Are there any other specific compile-time or link-time options required to export symbols in the new Clang front end?

Note :- The source code cannot be shared publicly. I apologize for that. I highly appreciate if anyone can provide some pointers.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to locate where the crash happens? Have you examined the values of all involved variables at the location of the crash? Crashes resulting from building with a different compiler (or a different version of the same compiler) or different platform usually is because of *undefined behavior* in the code. And since you can't show the code (even a [mcve] apparently) then we really can't help you more than this.

Comment: Have you tried creating a static library archive from the `.o`'s that feed the shared-object creation and linking against that? Did you build both components using the same compiler? Can you share your command line call when linking the shared `.o`, and also how you formed the shared library itself? You might try adding `-G -bexpall -bexpfull -bernotok` to the end of your command to see if it helps.